# Create Ansibles remote_tmp from config file variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, temp

I want to fix the following warning by manually creating the path:

```
Wednesday 22 January 2020  12:50:41 +0100 (0:00:05.878)       0:20:16.431 ***** 
[WARNING]: Module remote_tmp /home/db2inst1/.ansible/tmp did not exist and was created with a mode of 0700, this may cause issues when running as another user. To avoid this, create the remote_tmp dir with the correct permissions
manually
```

To keep things DRY, I don't want to just use the pattern in a `file` directive for creation. Instead, I'd like to access the `remote_tmp` variable inside my playbook to dynamically fetch the path, even when it's changed by environment variables or the `ansible.cfg` file.

I couldn't find a documentation about this variable and tried:

```
- debug:
    #var: remote_tmp
    #var: hostvars[remote_tmp]
    var: ansible_remote_tmp
```

but always got an error  that the variable is not defined.

How can I get the `remote_tmp` variable from the config inside a playbook?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand you just have to define

`allow_world_readable_tmpfiles: true` in your `vars.yml` file,
so somehow this solution works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below, if this is what you are looking for.

```
---
- hosts: "localhost"
  tasks:
  - name: ansible conf file
    shell: cat /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg | grep remote_tmp | awk '{print $3}'
    register: remote_tmp
  - name: print
    debug:
     msg: "{{remote_tmp.stdout}}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [print] 
****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "~/.ansible/tmp"
}
```

Comment: This would be a workaround. But I'm wondering that there seems no way to access the `remote_tmp` value directly as it is possible with other variables from Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no way to access the `remote_tmp` value directly as you can with other variables from Ansible.

I confirmed this by dumping all variables with `-vvv -m setup`. There is no `remote_tmp` in the output.

This is with Ansible 2.10.x

My guess is this is because `remote_tmp` is Ansible's temp directory for Ansible's internal use.  Not for us to store things in it.  :)  Because Ansible cleans up after itself but it wouldn't know to clean up our files.

Nevertheless, you could open an issue requesting to see the value of `remote_tmp` as an Ansible variable at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/new/choose

Also, that warning isn't anything to worry about -- Ansible is just letting you know it created a temp directory that's only writable by that user.  That is a responsible and secure thing to do.  Unless you have specific use case that requires different permissions on the remote_tmp directory, the default is most likely fine!